# Element not visible for check box though its available

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, checkbox, webdriver

I am trying to tick a checkbox using Selenium. The page looks like below.

[image]

Then when I click on edit, it changes to the below shown format.

[image]

At this time, I can select the checkbox from Chrome dev tools using the below shown xpath.

```
//input[@name='value[326071]']
```

Below is how the DOM looks.

[image]

I have put a thread wait before clicking on the check box. Below is my code.

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement assignWorkSpaceElement = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='value[326071]']"));
assignWorkSpaceElement.click();
```

I tried with the below xpath as well. Still no luck. I am debugging the code through IntelliJ and prior to going over the web element line, I am able to select the checkbox from Chrome dev tools. Its clearly there.

```
//*[contains(@class,'col-md-8')]//input[@name='value[326071]']
```

but when I execute the code, I get the following exception.

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565386 (45a059dc425e08165f9a10324bd1380cc13ca363),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see in your HTML it looks like the XPath you are locating has multiple elements...

Now, If you are trying to loop over all checkbox's and click that can be done with:

```
WebElement assignWorkSpaceElement = chromeDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='value[326071]']"));
for (WebElement el : assignWorkSpaceElement ) {
     el.click();
}
```

But if you just want the one element with the value=326071 you must add some more specific XPath something like:

```
WebElement assignWorkSpaceElement = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='value[326071]' and @type='checkbox' ]"));
assignWorkSpaceElement.click();
```

Or:

```
WebElement assignWorkSpaceElement = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='value[326071]' and @value='1' ]"));
assignWorkSpaceElement.click();
```

Hope this is helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

I Think you need to change your xpath,and don't use **thread.sleep** instead of that use **webdriver wait.**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
  WebElement e4 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-8- form-control-static']//following::input[1]")));

if(e4.isDisplayed())
{
  e4.click();
}
```